# what are the main different UIcontrols between ipad and iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am new to iPhone and iPad development. I would like to work with the iPad. So I would like to know the main difference between iPad and iPhone `UIControls`.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ideally no difference between UIControls of iPhone and iPad

for iPad there is extra control named `UIPopoverController` and `UISplitViewController`

Also, for iPad, keyboard always have button to dismiss, which is at right bottom.

Hope this info helps you

EDIT :-

Here is implementation and demo of [UIPopOverController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)

Comment: if you don't mind please tell me what is the use of UIPopoverController. Sorry for the disturb.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [**MobileHIG**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)  for the controls.

The major difference is there is two controls for iPad, those are not available for iPhone.

1. **UIPopoverController**
2. **UISplitViewController**